# Generate all possible combinations of 3 digits without repetition

Tags: c, algorithm, combinations

I'm trying to write a program that prints all possible combinations of three digits.
And there is the constraint that:

1. The three digits must be different
2. 012, 120, 102, 021, 201, and 210 are considered the same combination of the three digits 0, 1 and 2
3. Print only the smallest combination of three digits

The expected output is as follows

> 012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, 024, 025, 026, 027, 028, 029, 034, 035, 036, 037, 038, 039, 045, 046, 047, 048, 049, 056, 057, 058, 059, 067, 068, 069, 078, 079, 089, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 156, 157, 158, 159, 167, 168, 169, 178, 179, 189, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 256, 257, 258, 259, 267, 268, 269, 278, 279, 289, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 356, 357, 358, 359, 367, 368, 369, 378, 379, 389, 456, 457, 458, 459, 467, 468, 469, 478, 479, 489, 567, 568, 569, 578, 579, 589, 678, 679, 689, 789

I'm trying to implement in C but the algorithm or any language implementation will suffice.

Here is what I've done so far but it's inacurrate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * main - entry point
 *
 * Description: display triple digits and ,
 *
 * Return: Always 0 (successful)
 */

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k, l;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 1000)
    {
        j = i / 100; /* hundreds */
        k = (i / 10) % 10; /* tens */
        l = i % 100; /* units */
        if (j < k && k < l)
        {
            putchar(l + '0');
            putchar(k + '0');
            putchar(j + '0');
            if (i < 789)
            {
                putchar(',');
                putchar(' ');
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: how is 012 singled out the valid number? ... why not 201?

Comment: 012 is the smallest triple number without any of the digits being repeated. 000, 001, 002, ..., 010, 011. all have at least a digit being repeated.

Comment: It should be `l = i % 10`. Do you see why? Try it on a few numbers.

Comment: Also, that's an awful algorithm. For three-digit numbers I guess it's acceptable, but as the length increases, the ratio of selected numbers to candidates gets steadily lower.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that `l = i % 10` is accurate instead. Also, I reversed the order of `k, j, l` in `putchar()`. About the algorithm performance can you suggest a better one, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Suppose you have a qualifying number. What's the next one? You know the digits are in order, so the last digit is the largest. If it's not nine, you can just increment it. If it is nine, you need to go back to the previous digit. If it's not eight, you can increment it and put the next larger digit after it. If it is eight, go back one more position... if you get to the beginning without finding a digit which you can increment, you're done.

Comment: You want to print 10^2, 10^1, and 10^0... Your sequence of `putchar( )` calls is back to front... Why not use meaningful **names** instead of meaningful **comments**. The compiler disposes of all comments without reading them...

Comment: If the goal is to make the fastest code, use `puts("012, 013, 014, ,,,, 679, 689, 789");`.  OTOH, good programming handles variations in the programming goal without a great need to significantly re-factory code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That sounds like a fun thing to try... `:-)` Just did... `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly compact snippet of code for giving the smallest unique three-digit number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char digit[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 9; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < 10; k++)
            {
                digit[0] = i + '0';
                digit[1] = j + '0';
                digit[2] = k + '0';
                digit[3] = '\0';
                printf("%s\n", digit);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can give that a try.

Comment: can move `digit[3] = '\0';` above all the loops, or simply `char digit[4] = {0};` and omit it entirely, but this is great!

Comment: Good point.  Would make the loop more compact.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", digit);` can be move to before loops.  `digit[0] = i + '0';` can be move to before `for (int j = i....`.  `digit[1] = j + '0';` can be moved before `for (int k = j  ...`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I get moving the assignments,, but where can the `printf` be moved ..?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", digit);` is fine where it is.  I meant `digit[3] = '\0';` can be moved before the loop.

Comment: Could forget about the '\0' completely, use `char digit[ 3 ];` and `printf( "%.*s", sizeof digit, digit );`

Comment: Could even move each assignment ahead of its successor's `for()`. Improve "locality" of operations. Final interior loop is just "assign final char and print the array"... Many ways to do this... `:-)`

Comment: is anybody reading these comments before they comment?? Goodness.

Comment: @yano "Goodness" might include pointing out the "pre-knowledge" of each loop's upper boundary and how those "magic numbers" will come back to bite if this concept is applied in other circumstances... Where does it end?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some annotated code that might improve the outcome.

```
char *sep = ""; // the separator to use. Put this line ahead of the loop
```

and

```
// meaningful names mean no comment required
// EDIT: thank you, @Chux
int unit = i      % 10;
int tens = i / 10 % 10;
int hund = i /100 % 10;

if ( unit < tens && tens <  hund )
    printf( "%s%c%c%c", sep, hund + '0', tens + '0', unit + '0' ), sep = ", ";
```

Notice that 'j', 'k' and 'l' have no *meaning* to this problem. Easy to `putchar()` the numbers in **reverse** order without noticing...

Of course, if this is not a homework assignment (Prof wouldn't believe you wrote this)...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *sep = "", *dgts = "0123456789";
    for( int h = 0; dgts[h]; h++ )
        for( int t = h+1; dgts[t]; t++ )
            for( int u = t+1; dgts[u]; u++ )
                printf( "%s%c%c%c", sep, dgts[h], dgts[t], dgts[u] ), sep = ", ";
    putchar( '\n' );
    return 0;
}
```

And, to use the equivalence of `array addressing` and `pointers`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char *h, *t, *u, *sep = "";
    for( h = "0123456789"; *h; h++ )
        for( t = h+1; *t; t++ )
            for( u = t+1; *u; u++ )
                printf( "%s%c%c%c", sep, *h, *t, *u), sep = ", ";
    putchar( '\n' );
    return 0;
}
```

Inspired by comment by @Chux, here is the same thing expanded to printing 4 digits. Comparison will show the few trivial alterations needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char *m, *h, *t, *u, *sep = "";
    for( m = "0123456789"; *m; m++ )
        for( h = m+1; *h; h++ )
            for( t = h+1; *t; t++ )
                for( u = t+1; *u; u++ )
                    printf( "%s%c%c%c%c", sep, *m, *h, *t, *u), sep = ", ";
    putchar( '\n' );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not validate terrible code formatting by using it in an answer. Including replacing `;` with `,`.

Comment: @Chris I've restored the whitespace to increase legibility. Comma is a valid (underused) part of the C syntax. Look at the "replacement of `;`" in the variable declaration line. Avoiding appropriate use of `,` to account for "personal taste" is... well... a matter of taste. `:)` Did you comment on the other answer including an unnecessary header file?

Comment: Nope. Just edited it directly. While the comma is valid, it's excessively clever for the sake and just saves you from typing some braces.

Comment: @Chris The name of the language is the same as the first letter of "clever"... We all operate at our own level (incl. admitting my many mistakes and omissions). Even newbies will encounter "clever" constructs on their journey. Answers should, imo, take newbies beyond the confines of their acquired understanding. The short answer to this OP is "you're printing the digits in the wrong order" (see comments under the OP...) All other answers depart from the OP code with their own version... Who's being "excessively clever"? Just me???

Comment: @Chris `for( char *tok = str; ( tok = strtok( tok, ";" ) ) != NULL; tok = NULL ) ...` Is this **single invocation** of `strtok( )` "excessively clever"? It is, I believe, the intended usage of the library function, but... Most instances one sees involve two invocations and a while loop... What one person considers "clever" another may consider "insightful".

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char h = '0', t = '1', u = '2';

    while ((h <= '7') || (t <= '8') || (u <= '9')) {
        printf ("%c%c%c, ", h, t, u);
        u != '9' ? ++u : (t != '8' ? (++t, u = t + 1) : (++h, t = h + 1, u = t + 1));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, 024, 025, 026, 027, 028, 029, 034,
035, 036, 037, 038, 039, 045, 046, 047, 048, 049, 056, 057, 058, 059, 067, 068,
069, 078, 079, 089, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138,
139, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 156, 157, 158, 159, 167, 168, 169, 178, 179, 189,
234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 256, 257, 258, 259, 267,
268, 269, 278, 279, 289, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 356, 357, 358, 359, 367, 368,
369, 378, 379, 389, 456, 457, 458, 459, 467, 468, 469, 478, 479, 489, 567, 568,
569, 578, 579, 589, 678, 679, 689, 789,
```

Explanation:

- In the program - `h`, `t` and `u` represents digit at hundredth location, digit at tenth location and digit at unit location respectively in a three digit number.
- Initialised `h` with `'0'`, `t` with `'1'` and `u` with `'2'` because `012` is the smallest three digit number without any of the digits being repeated.
- `while` loop condition `((h <= '7') || (t <= '8') || (u <= '9'))` because `789` is biggest three digit number which follow constraint of - smallest combination of three digits without any of the digits being repeated. Any other combination of `7`, `8` and `9` will be bigger than `789` and any three digit number bigger than `789` will violat one of the given constraints.
- If you find it difficult to understand the expression with ternary operation

  ```
        u != '9' ? ++u : (t != '8' ? (++t, u = t + 1) : (++h, t = h + 1, u = t + 1));
  ```

  then here is simplified version using `if` `else` :

  ```
        if (u != '9') {
            ++u;
        } else {
            if (t != '8') {
                ++t;
                u = t + 1;   // due to given constraint, u will always greater than t
            } else {
                ++h;
                t = h + 1;   // due to given constraint, t will always greater than h
                u = t + 1;   // due to given constraint, u will always greater than t
            }
        }
  ```

Comment: Minor: OP is looking for `... 789`, not `... 789,`

Comment: `(++h, t = h + 1, u = t + 1)` ==> `(++h, u = (t = h + 1) + 1)` saves 1 character... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 `u != '9' ? ++u : (t != '8' ? (u = (++t) + 1) : (u = (t = (++h) + 1) + 1));` saves more than `1` character .... ;-).

Comment: Careful... Some people don't like "excessively clever" code... `:-)`

Comment: Exactly.. that's why it's in comment and not in the answer.. ;-) ....

Comment: Look at the 2UV answer... Even _comments_ are subject to scrutiny... `:-)`

Comment: Agreed.. Some people don't like "excessively clever" comments as well.. `;-D` ....

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I went about my solution:

```
int main(void)
{
        int a, b, c;

        for (a = 0; a < 8; a++)
        {
                for (b = a + 1; b < 9; b++)
                {
                        for (c = b + 1; c < 10; c++)
                        {
                                if (a != b && a != c && b != c)
                                {
                                        putchar(a + '0');
                                        putchar(b + '0');
                                        putchar(c + '0');
                                        if (a + b + c < 24)
                                        {
                                                putchar(',');
                                                putchar(' ');
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        putchar('\n');
        return (0);
}
```

The variables in order of a, b, & c; a for 1st digit, b for 2nd and c for 3rd.

The use of b = a + 1 & c = b + 1 was an idea given to me by user @chux - Reinstate Monica in another post that linked me to this one that involved two integers instead of 3 (For two digits, the code only needs to be slightly tweaked to cater for 2 integers).

Moving on.

The if statements:

```
if (a != b && a != c && b != c)
```

and

```
if (a + b + c < 24)
```

will filter out the duplicates and ensure that the comma and space are not applied to the last combo of integers respectively (i.e. 789, which sum up to give 24).