# How to calculate the number of triangles that can be formed

Tags: c

The code below should have counted the number of triangles that can be formed out of every triplet of 3 distinct integers from the given range 1...N. However, when I input 5, it gives me 34, while the right answer is 3: the only possible triangles are (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 5) and (3, 4, 5).

```
 // C code to count the number of possible triangles using

  #include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {   int N, count=0;
      setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
      printf("Please input the value of N: \n");
      scanf("%d", &N );
      for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
          for (int j = 1; j < N; j++) {
              // The innermost loop checks for the triangle
              // property
              for (int k = 1; k < N; k++) {

                  // Sum of two sides is greater than the
                  // third
                  if (i + j > k && i + k > j && k + j > i)
                  {
                      count++;
                  }
              }
      }

  }
      printf ("Total number of triangles possible is %d ",count);
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: "triplet of 3 distinct integers" Where do you care about that constraint?

Comment: I thought that my input N is the range, for example when I input 5, it means that the range is from 1 to 5. And triplet of 3 distinct integers are i, j and k.

Comment: your cycle limits are wrong: they should be `for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)`, `for (int j = i+1; j <= N; j++)` and `for (int k = j+1; k <= N; k++)` - your current version skips `N` and allows for repeated combinations including equal numbers

Comment: A number is not a range. What you want is "the range from 1 to given number `N`". Precision is important.

Comment: Do you consider the triangle `(3,4,5)` same or different than `(4,3,5)`?

Comment: They are different

Comment: Then how is the correct answer 3? You can use (2,3,4), (2,4,5), (3,4,5) and all 6 permutations for each of them

Comment: If these triangles are considered to be different, then the correct result should be 18 instead of 3.

Comment: @Gerhardh Well, this statement from the OP contradicts the description that "3 is the right answer for 1-5"... Shape shifters, some of these questions... Just when you think you've got a solution, the context switches to something novel... Should we argue that a triangle is a geometric concept, not an instance, therefore rotation and mirroring change nothing substantial about it??? Fun, eh? `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 well, that's a common problem on SO (for homework like questions) that the question does not necessarily reprocude the complete and/or correct requirements from the task description. Maybe because they are not fully understood or simply ignored. We don't know where the so called "correct" answer comes from. The OP or from the task. One might also argue that rotating a triangle within a plane is considered to be same while mirroring it would be a different triangle. Let's just keep the decision to the OP. I've pointed out the issue, they have everything at hand they need.

Comment: @Gerhardh You've hit the nail on the head... Ask the RIGHT question and the answer is almost too easy... `:-)` I've posted my own answer in the past few moments... Let's see what happens... Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: Reverted the last changes. Please do not change the content of your questions to make it point in totally different direction, after answers were provided. That is not how StackOverflow works. No one can benefit from this question if you make it a moving target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not ensure that the numbers are distinct.

You can do this be chosing your loop limits correctly:

```c
      for (int i = 1; i <= N-2; i++) {
          for (int j = i+1; j <= N-1; j++) {
              for (int k = j+1; k <= N; k++) {
```

Start each inner loop one higher than current counter of outer loop. It also does not make any sense to run each loop up to `N`. If they must be distinct, you can stop at `N-2, N-1, N`

---

This creates triples where numbers are increasing.
If you consider triangles `(3,4,5)` and `(4,3,5)` to be different, we must also account for permuations of these triples.
As all values are distinct, we have 6 possible permutations for each triple that was found in the inner loop.

Comment: Because the numbers are in ascending order, the check `i + j > k` is enough — no need to do all 3 checks.

Comment: @anatolyg what 3 checks? Do you mean adjusting the limits for the loops? Why should I use `<=N` three times if I know in advance that we cannot find anything for `i==N-1`)

Comment: Well, if you know in advance, then why start the whole thing with 1... None of these triangles is a triangle if one side is 1... Look at the OP's example with 1-5... Save another iteration searching for the impossible. `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 I could do, but main reason to post an answer is to solve the errors the OP made, not turn everything inside out to optimize every tiny detail.

Comment: Have it your way... It's your answer... All good... Just gave a UV to another answer that DID recognise this aspect of the problem. (It's just that, forgive me... Kicking off with 2 would be far less change to the OP code than changing two conditionals to bail out early. Especially that using N for all three loops wouldn't enter the nested loops but starting with 1 WILL enter the nested loops for no purpose.. (a fact known in advance).) Anyway, not my beer... Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: I think @anatolyg was trying to make an observation that although _in general_ the test to determine if 3 side lengths are a triangle, is to use the triangle inequality theorem, which states _"the sum of 2 sides of a triangle must be greater than the third side."_ so adding together each combination of 2 sides to see if it's greater than the third side is sufficient, in general.  But because in this case the numbers are arranged in sequence, that only one of the three test should be sufficient.   I have not tested his observation, but I think that is what he was intending to suggest.

Comment: (OP uses this here: `if (i + j > k && i + k > j && k + j > i)`)  ...but after all that, its really a moot point as your answer addresses the question just as it is.

Answer (score 1):

### You need to do the following:

- run first loop through 1 to N, i.e.: `1 <= i <= N`
- don't start each nested loop from index 1. So, you need to run first nested loop in range `i+1 <= j <= N` and second nested loop in range `j+1 <= k <=N`.

### Explanation

- First, if you run all 3 loops from 1 to N, then you are not doing distinct counting because all numbers in the range will be iterated 3 times. So it would give an incorrect result.
- Secondly, since we need to count distinct numbers only, it is efficient to count `+1` from the previous outer loop each time. In this way, we are ensuring that we are not iterating over any number twice.

**Check the following code:**

```
 // C code to count the number of possible triangles using

  #include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {   int N, count=0;
      setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
      printf("Please input the value of N: \n");
      scanf("%d", &N );
      for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
          for (int j = i+1; j <= N; j++) {
              // The innermost loop checks for the triangle
              // property
              for (int k = j+1; k <= N; k++) {

                  // Sum of two sides is greater than the
                  // third
                  if (i + j > k && i + k > j && k + j > i)
                  {
                      count++;
                  }
              }
      }

  }
      printf ("Total number of triangles possible is %d ",count);
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Here, too... None of the sought after triangles will ever have a side of length 1... Start the search with 2...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I can't go for a comment so let's go for an answer.
I don't really get what you wish to do. As I am understanding it, you wish to print this :
1, 2, 3, 4, 5-> [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5] -> 3

Except, with your code, you'll never check your N since you go out of your loop when i turns into N.

Also, your "j" and "k" don't have to move starting 1 since you already tried that position with "i", so you'll only get doublons doing that.

EDIT : some changes for a smarter code (I removed my +1 but go check for "<=", which I personnaly dislike :) ):

```
// since [1, 2, 3] can't bring any triangle
if (N < 4) return 0; 

// since there is no possible triangle with 1 as a border, start at 2 
for (int i = 2; i <= N-2; i++) {
          for (int j = i+1; j <= N-1; j++) {
              // The innermost loop checks for the triangle
              // property
              for (int k = j+1; k <= N; k++) {

                  // Sum of two sides is greater than the
                  // third
                  // simplified as suggested by S M Samnoon Abrar
                  if (i + j > k)
                  {
                      
                      count++;
                  }
              }
      }
```

Comment: Well, we can see that author has an issue with his first condition, starting at i=1 but stopping at i = N-1. I prefer to start counting from 0 to N-1, so for (int i=0; i < N; i++), and "manually" add 1 to each value. 
pos[0] = 1 | pos[1] = 2 | etc

Comment: Just did, with some conditions and explanations as why not calculating for N < 4 and why I start at i=2 instead of 1 :)

Comment: UV for the ONLY answer provided that recognised starting with 1 was a waste of time... Well done... Take a bow... `:-)`

Comment: Thx for the upvote, but my quiver is empty of arrows. Do you have one of stars to replace ? (yes, it's me trying to make a joke between pointers in pascal (^) and in C (*), and I fear that not enough peeps will have the reference (ahah) so i have to explain it.. ).

Comment: @Fe2O3 : considering OP is waiting for 3 as an answer, i think the code should only look for unique results (as in "no permutation"). 

Also, as you can see in your results, OP code as to find possibilities for N as biggest side, but since limits are "<N" instead of "<= N", your code only checks for 2, 3 and 4, missing 5. 

all that together, it means you don't have to start at 1 (or 2) for "j" and "k" because you're not looking after permutations, and still border "i<=N-2", "j<=N-1" and "k<=N". Since "k" is then always bigger than "i" and "j", you test only "k<i+j".

Comment: I mean, we are sure since j=i+1, and k=j+1 that i<j<k is always true.

Comment: It's hard to know WHAT the OP wants. Puzzled by 34, Expecting 3, Showing 5 yet code uses '<' instead of '<=', All counters start at 1 (acknowledged as impossible)... Typical bad question with contradictory evidence. My answer was simply to add the few lines to enforce unique digits and to print the values being counted (for inspection)... Had the OP used even just the single print statement, this question may not have been asked... *sigh*

Comment: I may be wrong, but we're in september and it looks like a school exercise to learn how to read a table. Teacher may have given "5" and told "answer has to be "3". As most of new coders, they don't yet think of how to interpret limit and teacher has maybe shown an example with an iteration starting from 0 up to N, and student just changed the 0 to 1. But since they start counting from 1 and wish to check with 5, they have to reach <= N . Your code would work with "<=N" once you've removed doublons to get only "unique" results whatever permutations.

Comment: "My code" is that inner `if( )` block that does work. It's purpose was to show the OP how she could have figured out for herself what was happening... Thank you for the helpful advice. I do know what I'm doing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73668806/17592432 All good! `:-)`

Comment: What concerns me is beginners who are already struggling with new concepts are so often told "use a debugger" (another complex and sophisticated tool) when they are grappling with what code is and what a compiler is/might-be. imo, "helpful" is pointing out that a simple "print" statement here-or-there gives them a window into what the code is doing. They don't just see an incomprehensible final result and immediately jump on SO with pleas for assistance and "solving my problem by revising my code for me". A "teaching" moment, let's say. `:-)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248028/discussion-between-pluckplk-and-fe2o3).

Answer (score 1):

Spot the extra line of code that enforces the constraint that the 3 numbers are "distinct" (read "unique"). Funny what a little "print debugging" can turn up...

```
    printf("Please input the value of N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N );
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < N; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < N; k++) {
                if (i + j > k && i + k > j && k + j > i) {
                    if( i != j && j != k && k != i ) {
                        printf( "%d %d %d\n", i, j, k );
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("Total number of triangles possible is %d ",count);
```

Output

```
Please input the value of N: 5
2 3 4
2 4 3
3 2 4
3 4 2
4 2 3
4 3 2
Total number of triangles possible is 6
```

The OP code was counting (1,1,1) or (2,3,3) in contravention of "distinct" digits.

AND, there is now ambiguity from the OP person as to whether, for instance, (4,2,3) and (4,3,2) are distinct.

`printf()` - the coder's friend when things don't make sense...

Comment: Your code includes the initial error of OP that `N` is not included in the loops.

Comment: @Gerhardh That is deliberate. The code here is the OP code with the addition of the innermost `if()` and its code block. I didn't seek to revise the OP code to fix problems and improve efficiency, My purpose in this answer was to demonstrate how "self help" might have given the OP less stresss and a clear path forward without leaning on SO. That the OP description and code is flawed goes without saying. "Teach a man to fish, feed him for a lifetime..." `:-)`